# Nextjs receiving an unexpected stringified object query "[Object object]" in getServerSideProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, next.js

TLDR:

```
  query: { token: '[object Object]' },
  params: { token: '[object Object]' }
```

My pages folder has this structure

```
+---catalog
|   |   index.tsx
|   |   products.tsx
|   |
|   \---[slug]
|           index.tsx
|           products.tsx
|
```

The problem is that when I visit `http://localhost:3000/catalog/products`, the `getServerSideProps` receive a query of

```
{
   slug: "[Object object]"
}
```

Yes, a string, not an object, but it should be an empty object and it was, this was working and this drove me mad really, I didn't really touch the nextjs code, but here is `/catalog/products`

```
import Page from './[slug]/products';
export { getServerSideProps } from './[slug]/products';
export default Page;
```

and here's `/[slug]/products/`

```
// react
import React from 'react';
// application
import getShopPageData from '~/store/shop/shopHelpers';
import ShopPageShop from '~/components/shop/ShopPageShop';
import { wrapper } from '~/store/store';

export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(async (context) => {
    await getShopPageData(context);
});

function Page() {
    return (
        <ShopPageShop
            layout="grid"
            gridLayout="grid-4-sidebar"
            sidebarPosition="start"
        />
    );
}

export default Page;
```

here's wrapper

```
import { createWrapper, MakeStore } from 'next-redux-wrapper';

export const wrapper = createWrapper<IRootState>(makeStore);
```

`context.query / context.params` both receive a stringified object when I visit the URL I mentionted, a slug of "[Object Object]" goes to the method that gets the product with the slug, which causes issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 months of searching, this is the most stupid problem ever, tried chrome & edge and there was something wrong, I figured out that there's (I think) a chrome extension that missed up this, everything is working and the code is correct, I didn't realy figure if this is right yet, I just used firefox to test my theory and it worked.

Here's what happened:

- Use chrome, 2 requests are made to the same endpoint, the first one gets the slug right, the second one gets "[object Object]"
- Use FF or whatever, 1 request happens sucessfully

Chrome has more than 15 extensions here, I disabled all and tested, still not working, I'll leave chrome for a while untill I know the reason.

Comment: I had a similar problem and found that I was making an `<img src={ `${imageUrl} `} />` type request, but `imageUrl` was coming back as an object instead of a string, leading to it requesting `[object Object]` from the server. Might be useful for future googlers to check which request is sending `[object Object]` and start looking there.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing [slug] into [...slug].

Comment: I'm only matching catalog/<slug>/products/